# Swift Spritekit Adding Button programmatically

Tags: swift

How do I programmatically add a button that will run an action when it's clicked? What code would be used?

I am used to just adding a button in the storyboard and running an IBAction from there.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Adding a button in SpriteKit and responding to taps on it is not quite as easy as it is in UIKit. You basically need to create an `SKNode` of some sort which will draw your button and then check to see if touches registered in your scene are within that node's bounds.

A really simple scene with just a single red rectangle in the center acting as a button would look something like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
class ButtonTestScene: SKScene {
    var button: SKNode! = nil
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Create a simple red rectangle that's 100x44
        button = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 44))
        // Put it in the center of the scene
        button.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:self.frame.midY);
        self.addChild(button)
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Loop over all the touches in this event
        for touch in touches {
            // Get the location of the touch in this scene
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            // Check if the location of the touch is within the button's bounds
            if button.contains(location) {
                print("tapped!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need a button that looks and animates like the ones in UIKit, you'll need to implement that yourself; there's nothing built in to SpriteKit.

Answer (score 15):

I have created a class SgButton (https://github.com/nguyenpham/sgbutton) in Swift to create buttons for SpriteKit. You can create buttons with images, textures (from SpriteSheet), text only, text and background images/texture. For example, to create button with image:

```
SgButton(normalImageNamed: "back.png")
```

Create button with textures:

```
SgButton(normalTexture: buttonSheet.buy(), highlightedTexture: buttonSheet.buy_d(), buttonFunc: tappedButton)
```

Create round corner text button:

```
SgButton(normalString: "Tap me", normalStringColor: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(200, 40), cornerRadius: 10.0, buttonFunc: tappedButton)
```

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? Don't you guy respect the contribution from other people?

Comment: I'm using your solution and it works great - not sure why this was originally down voted.

Comment: @Tony worry non, your class is very good, it only need a few updates to work with the latest syntax and UITouch changes introduced...

Comment: I cannot use SgButton now. After I import it by pod, build failed. I don't know whether I can edit it in xcode or not. Hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

**Mike S - Answer updated for - Swift 5.2**

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        createButton()
        
    }

func createButton()
    {
        // Create a simple red rectangle that's 100x44
        button = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 44))
        // Put it in the center of the scene
        button.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:self.frame.midY);
        
        self.addChild(button)
        
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
            // Check if the location of the touch is within the button's bounds
            if button.contains(touchLocation) {
                print("tapped!")
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: This works, if the "button" is a child of the SKView, however if one makes the button the child of another SKSpriteNode or a camera, then this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OOButtonNode](https://github.com/ooleynich/OOButtonNode).
Text/Image buttons, Swift 4.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I think that all necessary information is in this topic. According to context this link direct to library on the GitHub with SpriteKit button implementation :-)

Answer (score -6):

```
          func tappedButton(theButton: UIButton!) {
                println("button tapped")
           }
        }
```

The above code prints out button tapped when the button is tapped.

P.S. the swift ebook is a really good guide for the new programming language.

Comment: I think he wants to ask about how to add that button in the first place; before adding its action-on-click..

Comment: He asked for it programmatically

Comment: Thanks bro, I appreciate for trying.  I am going to look into the swift ebook also.  Thanks for showing me about the book! :)