# how do you create buttons in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button

I am currently developing a game using swift with xCode and I'm not quite sure how to make a button "pressable". I usually do something like this:

```
var button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"sample")
button.xScale = 1
button.yScale = 1
button.name = "pressHere"
```

and then in the touchesBegan function I do this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if (node.name == "pressHere") {
        //whatever I want the button to do
    }
}
```

I've found that if I do this method a lot my game will crash. Perhaps this isn't really what causes the issue, but it's always helpful learning a new way :)

Comment: If you have a question about a crash, update your question with details about the crash.

Comment: no my question isn't about the crash, it's simply about how to create a button

Comment: I don't like to override the behavior of `-touchesBegan` by self. `UIGestureRecongizer` will be your good friend.

Comment: seen this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-create-button-programmatically-in-swift

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225236/swift-spritekit-adding-button-programaticly

Answer (score 0):

[Swift Spritekit Adding Button Programaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225236/swift-spritekit-adding-button-programaticly)

This Link posted by Gavidi Harikrishna answered my question completely. I hope it also reaches who ever seeks the same answer