# Creating a button using SKLabelNode as a parent in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I'm trying to create a subclass of SKLabelNode for a button in SpriteKit. I tried to create a button using SKLabelNode as a parent, so I can use everything I know about labels while creating my buttons (font, text size, text color, position, etc).

I've looked into [Swift Spritekit Adding Button Programaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225236/swift-spritekit-adding-button-programaticly?answertab=votes#tab-top) and I'm using the basis of what that is saying, but rather I'm making a subclass instead of a variable, and I'm creating the button using a label's code. The subclass has the added function that will allow it to be tapped and trigger an action.

```
class StartScene: SKScene {

class myButton: SKLabelNode {

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
                if myButton.containsPoint(location) {

                // Action code here
                }
        }
    }
}

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let startGameBtn = myButton(fontNamed: "Copperplate-Light")
        startGameBtn.text = "Start Game"
        startGameBtn.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        startGameBtn.fontSize = 42
        startGameBtn.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height * 0.5)
        addChild(startGameBtn)

    }
}
```

My error is in: *if myButton.containsPoint(location)*

The error reads: *Cannot invoke 'containsPoint' with an argument list of type '(CGPoint)'*

I know it has to do something with my subclass, but I have no idea what it is specifically.

I also tried putting parentheses around *myButton.containsPoint(location)* like so:

```
if (myButton.containsPoint(location))
```

But then the error reads: *'CGPoint' is not convertible to 'SKNode'*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an alternative solution that would work the same way.
Change the following code

```
if myButton.containsPoint(location) {
```

To this and it should compile and have the same functionality

```
if self.position == location {
```

Comment: if it worked, mark this answer as solved so others who encounter the same problem can see it for visibility