# Swift 3.0: SKSpriteNode as Button does not work when given a non-SKView parent?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skcameranode

There are already a few questions out there regarding how to make a button in SpriteKit such as [Swift Spritekit Adding Button Programaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225236/swift-spritekit-adding-button-programaticly) and [Setting up buttons in SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/setting-up-buttons-in-skscene).

Either way, the solution is to make an `SKSpriteNode` with a texture for the button and then in the function `touchesEnded`, test to see if the touch falls within the button-`SKSpriteNode`.

Interestingly, however, is that if one were to make the button a child to, say a `SKCameraNode`, or another `SKSpriteNode`, then this method no longer works.

My question is why? and how to overcome this dilemma.

#### UPDATE:

In regards to the post below here are two alternate version of simple GameScene.swift file. The main difference is that in the first case, `sprite2` is not a child of the camera, whereas in the version 2 it is.

Note: In the gifs, notice how on version 1, clicking the purple sprite (`sprite2`) causes it to print "You tapped the purple sprite.", whereas it says "blue sprite" in version 2.  Thus the issue is made clear:

**Tapping the child of another SKNode registers as tapping the uppermost parent node, rather than as the node actually tapped!**

New question: How to correct this.

Addendum: in version 2 `sprite2` has changed positions a bit due to becoming a child of the camera - as it is an M.W.E. and it doesn't impact this demonstration, I chose not to correct it.

## Version 1

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var cam: SKCameraNode!

    var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite")
    var sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite2")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = SKColor.white

        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/4,y: size.height/2)
        sprite2.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/4 * 3,y: size.height/2)

        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)

        // Set up the camera
        cam = SKCameraNode()
        self.camera = cam
        cam.setScale(3.0)

        cam.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/4, y: 0)
        sprite.addChild(cam)



        addChild(sprite); addChild(sprite2)


    }


    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    }

    func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    }

    func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

        if sprite.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("You tapped the blue sprite")
        }

        if sprite2.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("You tapped the purple sprite")
        }

    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

### [image]

## Version 2

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var cam: SKCameraNode!

    var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite")
    var sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite2")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = SKColor.white

        // Scale Sprites
//        sprite.setScale(0.3)
        sprite2.setScale(0.3)

        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/4,y: size.height/2)
//        sprite2.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/4 * 3,y: size.height/2)

        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)

        // Set up the camera
        cam = SKCameraNode()
        self.camera = cam
        cam.setScale(3.0)

        cam.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/4, y: 0)
        sprite.addChild(cam)



        addChild(sprite); //addChild(sprite2)
        cam.addChild(sprite2)


    }


    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    }

    func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    }

    func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

        if sprite.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("You tapped the blue sprite")
        }

        if sprite2.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("You tapped the purple sprite")
        }

    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you using `touchesEnded` in the `SKScene` holding your buttons and camera, or on the subclass of `SKSpriteNode` that is your button instances?

Comment: `touchesEnded` in the `SKScene` holding the buttons and camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think what you're saying is true.  You can detect a touch from a child node. To demonstrate, I just ran a little test code within one of my SpriteKit projects where I detected touch on my camera node

```
var cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
```

Then in `didMove(to:)`:

```
addChild(cameraNode)
camera = cameraNode
camera?.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
```

Detect touch on `cameraNode` using `touchesEnded`:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    let location = touch.location(in: cameraNode)

    print("LocationX: \(location.x), LocationY: \(location.y)")
}
```

Here was my print out:

```
LocationX: -13.9129028320312, LocationY: 134.493041992188
```

To further explain, if you added a button as a child of your `cameraNode`, you would then do something like this:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    let location = touch.location(in: cameraNode)

    // Check if tap was within button frame (assuming your buttonNode is named button and a child of cameraNode)
    if button.frame.contains(location) {
        // Tap was within the frame of the button
        // Do whatever is necessary
    }
}
```

**Further Edit -**

Your problem stems from the node in which you are requesting the touch location. As I mentioned in my answer you need to extrapolate the touch location based on the node within which you're check the sprite's frame. In your edit you are detecting touch only on `self`, which will then give you coordinates relative to your `scene`. If you want to detect touch on a subview like the camera node, you need to request the touch location within the camera node.  Here is what I'm talking about based on the code you added:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    // This will give you touch location from the camera node 'cam' NOT 'self'
    let cameraLocation = touch.location(in: cam)

    // This will give you touch location from the scene itself
    let sceneLocation = touch.location(in: self)

    if sprite.contains(sceneLocation) {
        print("You tapped the blue sprite")
    }

    if sprite2.contains(cameraLocation) {
        print("You tapped the purple sprite")
    }

}
```

I just tried this and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes, that works, I am saying if you have a sprite which is then child to your camera.

Comment: @SamNeuron - That's exactly what I'm talking about. When you add the sprite as a child of your `cameraNode`, then you detect the frame of the button respective to the frame of the `cameraNode`. It should still work the same.

Comment: even if the camera is also child to another Sprite?

Comment: @SumNeuron - Yes, that is not an issue. The `touchesEnded` detects touch on the screen, and then translates those coordinates to the requested node's coordinates

Comment: Please see update. Unfortunately one can not see the mouse cursor for some reason, but the point holds.

Comment: @SumNeuron - Please see my update once again. You're still not detecting touch in your camera node. You need to specify the node in which you are detecting touch. You are saying `self` which won't necessarily get the location of a touch in a subview like your camera node.